# Android Зависимости в сторонних библиотеках

Tags: android, gradle

Всем привет. Никак не могу понять как это работает, раньше все решалось методом тыка, а теперь как то не получается.

я добавил библиотеку в свои проект.

мои gradle module

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.test.test"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.6.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:26.1.0'
    compile 'gun0912.ted:tedpermission:2.1.0'
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.6.0"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'

    // Addition library
    compile 'com.github.Kennyc1012:BottomSheet:2.4.0'



    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.9.1'

    implementation 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:26.1.0'
}
```

я добавил библиотеку com.github.Kennyc1012:BottomSheet:2.4.0
но теперь у меня подчеркнуто красным (указано на скрине.)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Может ли кто нибудь объяснить как работает, и как определят какие библиотеки нужно подключать в таких случаях?

Comment: конфликт версий библиотек поддержки - везде вместо 26.1.0 поставте 27.0.1

Comment: и везде вместо compile - implementation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

У Gradle есть хорошая задача, которая помогает при любом конфликте зависимостей: запускаете `gradlew app:dependencies --configuration releaseCompileClasspath` (или `releaseRuntimeClasspath`) и получаете вывод всех зависимостей для указанного проекта `app`

Например у нас вывод:

```
releaseRuntimeClasspath - Resolved configuration for runtime for variant: release
+--- com.example:example-android:1.1.1
|    \--- com.example.example-sdk:example-core:3.3.4
|         +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:22.0.0 -> 26.1.0
|         +--- com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0
|         |    \--- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.8.0 -> 3.8.1
|         |         \--- com.squareup.okio:okio:1.13.0
|         +--- com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-jackson:2.3.0
|         |    +--- com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0 (*)
|         |    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.7.2
|         |         +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.7.0
|         |         \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.7.2
|         +--- com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.8.1
|         |    \--- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.8.1 (*)
|         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.1.0
|              +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.1.0
|              |    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0  // внимание сюда
|              |         \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:22.2.0 -> 26.1.0
|              \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:8.1.0
|                   \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.1.0 (*)
+...
+--- android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.0.0
|    +--- android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:1.0.3 (*)
|    +--- android.arch.core:common:1.0.0 (*)
|    +--- android.arch.core:runtime:1.0.0
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:26.1.0
|    |    \--- android.arch.core:common:1.0.0 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:support-fragment:26.1.0
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0 (*)
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:26.1.0
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:26.1.0
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:26.1.0
|    |         +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:26.1.0
|    |         \--- com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0 (*)
|    \--- android.arch.lifecycle:common:1.0.3 (*)
...
```

Здесь видно, что в абстрактном приложении support library поднимается с версии 22 до версии 26 из-за одной из библиотек, но одна из либ не обновилась (никто не потребовал) и осталась базовая из нашего приложения (или из библиотеки).

Есть 2 способа решения такой проблемы:

1. точечный - указать не обновившуюся либу как прямую зависимость для приложения в build.gradle (добавить `implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'`)
2. всё разом - добавить специальную `resolutionStrategy` для библиотек с group id `com.android.support`

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Но когда я указываю версию библиотеки 27 то градл ругается на **the support library should not use a different version than the compilesdkversion**, но если поднять **compileSdkVersion** до 27 ругаются уже кучу библиотек. И можете ли посоветовать, если я укажу все библиотеки до 27 версии, возможны ли еще какие либо проблемы потом?

Comment: Поменял большинство либ на 27, вроде без последствий )) спасибо. Помогли, и объяснили